# What ist the difference between these two (Haskell)

Tags: sorting, haskell

I was checking some codes then i tried to write one of them but i keep getting a parse '=' error but when i copy paste the code from the source it works fine so what is the difference between this;

```
quicksort2 :: (Ord a) =>  [a] -> [a]
quicksort2 [] = []
quicksort2 (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort2 [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort2 [a | a <- xs, a > x]      
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

and this ;

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

quicksort2 gets parse error but quicksort doesn't. So where is the difference?

the error -> .hs:5:26: parse error on input `='

Comment: Where's the parse error?

Comment: Copy+paste the full error message into your question please.

Comment: its on the biggerSorted

Comment: btw, keep this in mind before considering using quicksort in Haskell: http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_%28Haskell%29#Parting_thoughts

quicksort is intended to be used with arrays not lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One has tabs mixed in the indentation, while the other uses only spaces. This causes problems because whitespace is very significant in Haskell, and your editor may be configured with a different tab width than Haskell (which always uses 8). So it may look OK in your editor, but to the compiler the indentation is all messed up.

This is how your code looks to Haskell:

```
quicksort2 :: (Ord a) =>  [a] -> [a]
quicksort2 [] = []
quicksort2 (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort2 [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
            biggerSorted = quicksort2 [a | a <- xs, a > x]      
        in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
^^^^^^^^
There are tabs here on the two lines above.
```

This gives a syntax error because the bindings in the `let`-expression are not properly aligned.

In general, avoid using tabs for indentation in Haskell. Configure your editor to always use spaces and it'll save you a lot of headaches.